# random height in Wordpress with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a layout for post for a website running in wordpress and I am trying to achieve a "pinterest" look on the feed by randomizing the heights of the featured images but on the code that I am running right now creates blank gaps between elements how can I solve this issue that when an Image has a shorter height the item below it doesn't display next to its adjacent item but right at the bottom of it

```
   function post_featured_images_shortcode() {
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'orderby' => 'rand',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $output = '<div class="post-featured-images post-featured-images-hidden">'; // Add CSS class "post-    featured-images-hidden"
    $count = 0;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
        $title = get_the_title();
        $link = get_the_permalink();
        $output .= '<div class="post-featured-image-wrapper">';
        $output .= '<a href="' . $link . '" class="post-featured-image-link">';
        $output .= '<div class="post-featured-image" style="background-image: url(' . $image . ')">';
        $output .= '<div class="post-featured-image-title">' . $title . '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</a>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $count++;

        if ($count % 4 == 0) {
            $output .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        }
    }
    $output .= '</div>';

    // Add JavaScript to randomize the height of post-featured-image elements
// Add JavaScript to randomize the height of post-featured-image elements and create blank space
 $output .= '<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var containerHeight = $(".post-featured-images").height();
        $(".post-featured-image").css("visibility", "hidden"); // hide the images initially
        $(".post-featured-image").each(function() {
            var minHeight = containerHeight * 0.6; // Set a minimum height of 20% of container height
            var maxHeight = containerHeight * 0.8; // Set a maximum height of 40% of container height
            var randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight + 1)) + minHeight;
            $(this).css("height", randomHeight + "px");
            $(this).css("visibility", "visible"); // show the images after the heights are set
        });
    });
    </script>';

    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}
 add_shortcode ('post_featured_images','post_featured_images_shortcode');
 

I tried fixing this issue with css but nothing seems to be working, this is the current css 
.post-featured-images {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post-featured-image-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-featured-image-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post-featured-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 7%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post-featured-image:hover .post-featured-image-title {
    opacity: 1;
}

.post-featured-image-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.post-featured-images-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Any screenshots of the current view and the desired view?

Answer (score 0):

in Your code you can change in your current css and replace following code

```
 .post-featured-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px !important;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 7%;
        overflow: hidden;
   }
```